# Unity alert sound stuck on bark

Tags: 12.04, sound-theme

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04, using the unity-2d desktop, I changed the alert sound to a bark and now I can't change it back to anything else.  In Sound Settings, under the "Sound Effects" tab, in the "Choose an alert sound" list, I select "default" or "glass" or "sonar" but I still get barks.

I'm testing by hitting backspace at a terminal prompt in gnome-terminal.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the dog?

Comment: I have the same issue.. I try to change the sound from the settings, but nothing, I'm stuck with the dog...

Comment: Who let the dogs out?

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming the file `bark.ogg` change the alert sound, and then rename the file back.  All this needs to happen as root.  You may have to restart your machine.

Also make sure that you set the volume past the mid point to get alert sounds to kick in

If that doesn't work, try creating a new entry in Startup Applications, as below.  Use any of the files in `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts` or use your own file, but place it in the same location.

[Also see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159467/ubuntu-12-04-64x-alert-sounds-dont-work)

This may or may not work, but its worth a shot.  You can try adding it in the Startup Application preferences.  Go to `System Preferences` --> `Startup Applications` and then find the GNOME login sound,

[image]

press `Edit` to change the command

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="your file name" --description="GNOME Login"
```

[image]

That's it

Comment: I think, he is saying changing the alert sound when something goes wrong. not Login sound

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `.pulse` folder and `.pulse-cookie` file in your home directory. To do this:

1. Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type this command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
    rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.pulse-cookie
   ```
3. Then restart your PC and select new alert sound.

Comment: Your answer just worked for me on Arch Linux running Gnome 40.2 on X11! I was able to find a faster way, I ran `mv ~/.pulse-cookie /tmp` then `pulseaudio --kill` (which auto-restarts pulseaudio), I didn't have to restart or logout. After killing `pulseaudio`, the new system sound that I had chosen in system settings immediately took effect in the terminal (dog > sonar). I think this is a bug or a gap in either Gnome or Pulseaudio and an upstream issue should probably be opened for it. I might get to it at some point but don't have the energy for it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but inverted problem (I wanted the bark as alert sound back) and could fix it with:

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/bark.ogg bell-window-system
```

If you want drip you might need to do:

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg bell-window-system
```