# Ubuntu 12.04 64x Alert Sounds dont work

Tags: 12.04, sound-theme

When using Ubuntu 12.04 i've aquired the need to use the system Alert Sounds.

I've been trying to make my SSH Shell play Alert Beeps ( "\a" ) back to me, but to no avail,
I finally figured out that it's not the ssh session itself, but the Alert Sounds altogether.

I've tried almost all the solutions out there, these have no result

```
Ubuntu Tweaks
echo -e "\a"
Turning up the volume in System Settings -> Sounds -> Sound Effects
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
beep
Changing the default Alert Sounds set to Ubuntu
Copying files in /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo to /usr/share/sounds
```

What i have noticed

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
```

returns "Option parsing failed: Cannot open display:"

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

returns ":0"

Going into *System Settings* -> *Sounds* -> *Sound Effects* and clicking on a sound makes it play, but when actually asking for the alert sound it wont play

The sounds wont play in "Guest" or other users either.

I'm using Gnome-Classic from package Gnome-Shell, but it also does not work in the default unity shell

Everything I have tried to get it to work returns no sounds whatsoever

Can anyone help me out with this one? I'm completely lost as to what else to try

Comment: I think you're looking for a system alert sound. Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/86502/re-enable-popping-sounds

Comment: Or answers from this question? http://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker Looks like pcskpr module is required

Comment: @medigeek That's exactly what i'm looking for, they're the "Alert Sounds" but they dont work at all. and i have indeed tried that. and the superuser link is NOT what i want, i want the local Alert Sounds to play, as i said, echo -e "\a" locally does not play

Comment: Hey, here's another one http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1979/16013 -- According to this answer "*this may not work when logged in remotely via SSH*" (or this answer for the "theory" http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1980/16013 )

Comment: Maybe you should try other terminals? Like xterm?

Comment: None of those help, It's not so much about the "Over SSH" bit as much as it is "I have no Alert Sounds at all"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo modprobe -v pcspkr
```

Then this should make a sound:

```
echo -e "\a"
```